# Chain rule 2nd order derivative without partial derivatives

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I have a function $v : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, and i define $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $g(r)=v(q+r\delta)$ where $q, \delta \in \mathbb{R}^d$.My goal is to compute $d^2g(r)$

I computed the first order derivative using the chain rule $$dg(r).z = dv(q+r\delta).z\delta$$

Then, i would like to compute the second order derivative but i don't know how i can do that.

Comment: Please do not use $\mapsto$ for $\to$ or $\rightarrow$. Since the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb R$, maybe it will be easier to write $g'(r)$. Why bother with $z$? It just confuses things.

Comment: @TedShifrin it's completely irrelevant but the penultimate two arrows you drew look the same on my screen. What's the difference between them? I know the difference between `\mapsto` and `\to`

Comment: @TedShifrin I wrote the equation with the z to stick to the general case, but maybe this is not the best idea here. So, without the z it would be $g'(r)=dv(q+r\delta)\delta$, right ?

Comment: @FShrike: Of course they're the same. But people prefer to use one or the other.

Comment: Cantor, yes. So now differentiate again. $d^2v$ is an $\Bbb R^d$-valued bilinear form, so you will be evaluating on $(\delta,\delta)$ and getting a vector answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, $g$ is defined on $\Bbb R$ so there's "only one variable" and your life is made easier. $g'(r)=\mathrm{d}v(q+r\delta)(\delta)$ and this is now a composition of things, again susceptible to the chain rule.

$$g':\Bbb R\overset{x\mapsto q+x\delta}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^d\overset{\mathrm{d}v}{\longrightarrow}\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^d;\Bbb R^d)\overset{\mathrm{eval}(\delta)}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^d$$

Let's focus on the first two maps. By the chain rule, their derivative is $h'(r)=\mathrm{d}^2v(q+r\delta)(\delta):\Bbb R\to\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^d;\Bbb R^d)$ (if you like, a matrix-valued function. $\mathrm{d}^2v$ is a less familiar object I believe sometimes called a tensor). $\mathrm{eval}$ is linear and is its own derivative (abusing language slightly) so overall (applying the chain rule to $\mathrm{eval}(\delta)\circ h$) we see: $$g''(r)=\mathrm{d}^2v(q+r\delta)(\delta)(\delta)$$In less formal notation, that's sort of like a Hessian and $g''(r)=\delta^T\mathrm{d}^2v(q+r\delta)\delta$ could be written *if you interpreted it carefully*. I don't think I recommend this. $\mathrm{d}^2v$ contains the data of, if you fix coordinates, the Hessian matrices of each coordinate function $\pi_i v$ for $1\le i\le d$, if that helps; a genuinely analogous matrix representation would, in full, have to be drawn in three dimensions.

*Much more simply*, $g''(r)$ is the vector of second derivatives of each projective $\pi_ig:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and these are simpler to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What is the meaning of $\cdot$ here ? And since $\delta \in \mathbb{R^d}$, i can't simplify $\delta \cdot \delta$ to $\delta^2$ no ?

Comment: @TedShifrin excuse me, I assumed $\delta$ was scalar without reading too carefully

Comment: @Cantor Apologies for misreading your question. I've edited

Comment: Okay thank you, i think i have an idea. I wasn't sure that $dv(q+r\delta)$ could be interpreted as $dv$ "composed" with $r \mapsto q+r\delta$ since it's a derivative at a given point.

Comment: just to be sure, $d^2v(q+r\delta) \in \mathcal{L}( \mathbb{R^d}, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^d} ,\mathbb{R^d} ) ) $ ?

Comment: @Cantor Yeah. If you like, you can identify that with $\Bbb R^{d\times d\times d}$ of $3D$-matrices